# how convert php socket script to C# code?

Tags: c#, php, tcp

I have tcp server running on linux and although I can run php -f test.php
on this server I need to do it from windows client and get results back.
php client script looks like this:

```
$Host = "192.168.2.70"; 
$Port = 8189;

$Socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die ("Error \n ".socket_strerror());
$Result = socket_connect($Socket, $Host, $Port) or die ("Error \n ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));

$message = 'CMD1;1;5;0;F;20130426;'."\n";

socket_write($Socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die ("Error \n ".socket_strerror());
$Result = '';

while($buf = socket_read($Socket, 2048 )) {
$Result = $Result.$buf;
}   

socket_close($Socket);
$handle = fopen ('./test.xml', "w");  

fwrite($handle, $Result, strlen($Result));  
fclose($handle);  

?>
```

and the C# client I ha like this:

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.70");
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress,8189);

Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

            try {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);
                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("'CMD1;1;5;0;F;20130426;'.'\n';");
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec));
```

Unfortunately it got connected but returns unknown command message. PHP script works locally fine but C# from windows client not, any tips ? cannot debug server code in linux.

thanks

Comment: Have you declared bytes?

Comment: Here's an example of Send and Receive:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/

Comment: yes:  byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];  I wonder if message formatting is good in c#.